# How can I format the current date and time and then use them in a variable in GoTest?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework, date

I use the keyword...

get date

But I have a date with the format like this

Sun May 11,2014 9:60 p.m.

I need to convert it in to this format 2014.05.11.09.60.60.321 I tried to put this yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.ff in the format arg field... I tried to put the format in the variable to, but its not working ether :(

I dont know what to do to use the current datetime (stamp) as a variable! [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. use the keyword : get current date
2. return variable, here an exemple ${stamp}
3. in the format arg, here an exemple %Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S.%f
4. now you can use the variable ${stamp}
   [image]